# Permissions, rights, roles, user groups, delegations

Tags: security, delegation, permissions, groups

I am looking for a good book, Internet resource that can clearly explain these terms.
Really, I would not like to read any Microsoft books or any book about windows or other operation systems. I really need the theoretical explanations.

I am appreciated to get any help.

Comment: Separate from implementation the words are pretty generic.  Just look them up the words in a [dictionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/) or [encyclopedia](http://www.wikipedia.org/)

Comment: Come on. I just look for a starting point to investigate this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be a good book. It is on information security, and has chapters on system security.

http://www.pearsonhighered.com/educator/academic/product/0,,0136004245-TOC,00%2ben-USS_01DBC.html

Comment: [Rob Slade's review is quite positive](http://victoria.tc.ca/int-grps/books/techrev/bkcmscpp.rvw).

Comment: @skhushalani. +1 any help, welcome!

Comment: We had this book for our Information Security class and I remember covering the topics you are talking about. It is probably the only textbook I actually enjoyed reading.

Answer (score 1):

Look at at [Rob Slade's reviews](http://victoria.tc.ca/int-grps/books/techrev/mnbkscgn.htm). His reviews are very good, because he doesn't hesitate to point out the defects in a book, and he explains what the book can bring to various audiences.

An excellent book covering security in general is [Ross Anderson's](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~rja14/book.html). An older edition is available online. He covers a wide range of topics, so after you've read the relevant chapters, you may want to follow some bibliographic references.

Comment: +1 Thanks, Gilles. It is a good starting point!